# Deduce a unique number from number

Tags: numerics

I work on the tree where each node has N children.

In my case each node has a unique identifier. i want to deduce an identifier of father node from the child identifier.

So, we can add an information on child identifier to deduce that for example: if the father's node is "123", the child node is "123.3" and then we deduce that the father of (123.3) is "123". but there is a problem where we have a large tree, then a node identifier can be "12.3.4.1.2.4.5...", not be a good solution.

What would be the best approach to generate a child identifier with a simple number and then deduce the father identifier (considering that it is unique in the entire tree)?

Comment: Why not just store the parent's id within the child node?

Answer (score 2):

How about encoding the path to the node as a binary, ternary, etc. (matching N) integer?  For example, the binary digits of 14 are `{1, 1, 1, 0}` and this could represent a path of  `right -> right -> right -> left`.  Or for a ternary tree, the ternary digits of 33 are `{1, 0, 2, 0}` and this could represent `middle -> left -> right -> left`.

Comment: Your idea is good but how can i apply it for tree when i have a node with N child ? and why 33 = `{1, 0, 2, 0}` ? what is your encoding ?

Comment: 33=3^3+2*3=1020 in ternary system

Comment: @Anton I mean `IntegerDigits[33, 3]` is `{1, 0, 2, 0}`.